# allow few users on a virtual directory

Tags: iis, authentication

How do I allow access only select few NT users to a ASP.NET website? I am hosting this application on IIS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What authentication type are you using? Integrated? ASP.NET roles?

If your using Integrated you can set up ACL permissions on the web sites folder on the server (right click->Security) and just add read permissions (if they will upload files to the site they will also needs write permissions). Then just set up your ASP.NET site to accept Integrated security and disable anonymous.

If I'm not clear enough and need more guided help, you'll need to tell us what version of Windows your server is using because the specific steps will differ depending on what version of IIS your using.

Comment: I am using windows integrated auth. Its a silverlight application hosted on IIS6 of a Windows Server 2008. I would need to tweak settings on web.config as well?

Comment: @johnc - "hosted on IIS6 of a Windows Server 2008" - I take it you really mean 2003?